# How Can I convert My Batch Script to an Executable and still run like a Bat Script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

When I try to use Simple Programs like `battoexe.exe` to convert my `.bat` to `.exe` and run it, it doesn't run like if i was to run straight from the Batch File...

My code for the Batch Script is this:

```
@echo off


:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------



net user administrator /active:yes

pause
```

If I ran the Batch File, It actually Enables the Administrator Account, however if I ran it as a `.exe` File, None of my Code In This Script Works...

How Do I get it to work or is there a good Program that Does this?

Comment: I test may of them. But the bat2exe converter is ridiculous. They just extract the bat file in temp folder and run them as usual. You have to code that exe file in C++/C# or other.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a try for this batch file to encode your file with base64 using `certutil` command utility by drag and drop your file over it :

```bat
@echo off
Title Encoding Batch Files With CERTUTIL Utility by Hackoo 2017
color 0A & Mode 80,5
If "%~1"=="" ( 
    color 0C & Mode 80,3
    echo(
    echo       You should drag and drop a file over this batch script to be encoded !
    Timeout /T 5 /nobreak>nul & exit /b
)
@for /f %%i in ("certutil.exe") do if not exist "%%~$path:i" (
  echo CertUtil.exe not found.
  pause
  exit /b
)
>"temp.~b64" echo(//4mY2xzDQo=
set "BOM_File=%~n1"
certutil.exe -f -decode "temp.~b64" "%BOM_File%"
del "temp.~b64"
@Copy "%BOM_File%" /b + "%~1" /b >nul 2>&1

set "TempFile=%Temp%\Temp_b64
set "OutputFile=%BOM_File%_encoded%~x0"
If exist "%OutputFile%" Del "%OutputFile%" >nul 2>&1
echo(
certutil.exe -f -encode "%BOM_File%" "%TempFile%"
(
    echo @echo off 
    echo Title Execution of "%~nx1" by Hackoo 2017
    echo CERTUTIL -f -decode "%%~f0" "%%Temp%%\%~nx1" ^>nul 2^>^&1 
    echo Start "" "%%Temp%%\%~nx1"
    echo Exit
)> "%OutputFile%"

@Copy "%OutputFile%" /b + "%TempFile%" /b >nul 2>&1
If exist "%TempFile%" Del "%TempFile%" >nul 2>&1
If exist "%BOM_File%" Del "%BOM_File%" >nul 2>&1
Timeout /T 2 /NoBreak>nul
```